# Is the cold start time related to function execution time in Serveless Computing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, aws-lambda

Is there a relationship between function cold start time and function runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per AWS observation (as noted [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-for-aws-lambda-predictable-start-up-times-with-provisioned-concurrency/))

> Runtimes like C# and Java have much slower initialization times than
> Node.js or Python, but significantly faster execution times once
> initialized

There are multiple benchmarks/experiments people have tried to come up with on measuring cold starts with different language runtimes  ( like [this](https://mikhail.io/serverless/coldstarts/aws/languages/)) and they all point to the similar observation.

AWS also provides "Provisioned Concurrency" which attempts to solve the problem of cold start.

Answer (score 0):

Your cold start time is related to the size of your lambda including 3rd party libraries you may be using with layers or directly in your deployment package. Your overall runtime will not affect the cold start unless you count the time it takes for the lambda to gather up the resources.

Answer (score 0):

In the Azure cold start can be connected with way of hosting your Azure Function. For example in the consumption plan after some idle time it could need some additional time to execute your request.
Using App Service Plan you can check whether you have
`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dedicated-plan#always-on`